# Searching key/values with defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm familiar with the use of the iteritems() and items() use with the standard dictionary which can be coupled with a for loop to scan over keys and values. However how can I best do this with the default dict. For example, I'd like to check that a given value does not show up in either the key or any of the values associated with any key. I'm currently trying the following:

```
for key, val in dic.iteritems():
    print key, val
```

however I get the following:

```
1 deque([2, 2])
```

and I have the following declarations for the variables/dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
clusterdict = defaultdict(deque)
```

So how do I best get at key values? Thanks!

Comment: Sot sure what you want, `dic.keys()` / `dic.values()` ?

Comment: You did get the value.  You get the deque object associated with the key of `1`.   What's wrong with what you got?

Answer (score 3):

In general, for a defaultdict *dd*, to check whether a value *x* is used as a key do this:

```
x in dd
```

To check whether *x* is used as a value do this:

```
x in dd.itervalues()
```

In your case (a defaultdict with deques as values), you may want to see whether *x* is in any of the deques:

```
any(x in deq for deq in dd.itervalues())
```

Remember, defaultdicts behave like regular dictionaries except that they create new entries automatically when doing `d[k]` lookups on missing keys; otherwise, they behave no differently than regular dicts.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question:

```
for key, val in dic.iteritems():
    if key!=given_value and not given_value in val:
        print "it's not there!"
```

Unless you meant something else...

Answer (score 1):

I made this for Python 3:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count_data = defaultdict(int)
count_data[1] = 10
query = 2
if query in count_data.values():
   print('yes')
```

> Edit

You can use Counter dictionary too:

```
from collections import Counter
count_data = Counter()
count_data[1] = 10
query = 2
if query in count_data.values():
    print('yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff = 'value to check'
if not any((suff in key or stuff in  value) for key, value in dic.iteritems()):
    # do something if stuff not in any key or value
```

Answer (score -2):

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

So you can use iteritems

Comment: If you look for some value in the dict the better way is dict.get('key') it return the value or None if no such key